# Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : # missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I've this data frame of a facebook page:

[image]

I run this code

```
ggplot(week, aes(x = week, y = likes)) + geom_col(fill = "cadetblue3", size =1, width = 0.5) + ggtitle('week Total Likes') + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = , face = "bold")) + theme_bw() + geom_text(aes(label = likes))
```

and it runs correctly

but when I knit Rmarkdown to html or pdf,,

[image: R gives me this ERROR]

where's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the code in a clean environment. The chunk may rely on variables from other code blocks earlier in your .Rmd that you have accidentially set to eval=FALSE.